# SWT table: how to make columns as wide as necessary

Tags: swt, jface, tableviewer

With Swing this was quite easy: iterate over all rows in a column and search the widest entry. SWT (or Windows?) supports the double click at the separator between table columns, but how to do that with SWT programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling yielded the following:

Try to use TableColumn.pack() as described in
http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools/msg60980.html

Comment: Thanks. :) Sometimes things are simpler than one initially thinks.